# How to answer user questions in interpersonal skills community?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am new to this stack community. The first thing I was blown away was the number of views each question garners within minutes. Would love to know a comparative stats of the different community from the stack exchange.

I attempted to pick a question and answer it. However, I felt ( plus few user comments add to my feeling) I am more judging the OP or concluding his situation. My counter-argument to that is ***how can you figure out an OP state of mind from his writing?*** Was he happy, or just passing his time or has deep pain or in excitement or in anger or confusion or seriously a genuine question`.

How do we know whether I just wasted sometime trying to answer or my thoughts really helped someone?

Comment: With 'passed sometime' do you mean 'wasted some time' ?

Comment: If you would be just judging the OP or drawing conclusions about the situation, err on the side of safety and don't answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

> How do we know whether I just wasted sometime trying to answer or my
>   thoughts really helped someone?

Most of the time you really don't know for sure, the green check-mark and/or upvotes may indicate that the OP/community liked your answer, but you don't really know if they took what you had to say to heart or took any action unless they follow up with an update or comment.

Sometimes you just do the right thing and hope for the best.

Hopefully what we're doing here helps the person who asked the question, but even if it doesn't maybe it helps someone somewhere who reads it down the line. If nothing else I know that the answers I write have helped me to be a slightly more mindful person... So that's at least one person I helped ;)

Comment: Yep. Writing helps self-improvement as well.